# Insert with Form from Convertkit in one line

Tags: html, ghost-blog

I am trying to put a form on my website in one single line but when the page loads, it changes to two lines. See the video here: https://www.loom.com/share/ea01ccbcec7d4ba19baaf899b5584017 in 0:03 you can see the original form and then it automatically changes to two lines.

Does anybody know what can cause this? I am using Ghost Blog and Convertkit form. I contacted their support team and they weren't able to sort this out for me.

Thanks a lot in advance

[image]